# Implementing model from repo error: truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, numpy, conda, h5py

I'm trying to reproduce the results from the Graph-RCNN model [here](https://github.com/jwyang/graph-rcnn.pytorch) and am running into an error when I try to train it. I know about the error "truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous", but I don't know when you can have syntax like that without throwing the error. Is a solution downgrading my version of Numpy? Generally, is there a likely package incompatibility error I should check first? Are there older versions of Numpy or h5py that don't throw this error. I just followed the instructions on the environment setup within the repo and installed everything using Conda. This is all in python 3.6.2 in a Conda environment

Notable package versions:

```
cython                    0.29.23          py36h2531618_0
h5py                      2.8.0           py36h3010b51_1003    conda-forge
mkl                       2020.4             h726a3e6_304    conda-forge
numpy                     1.19.2           py36h54aff64_0
numpy-base                1.19.2           py36hfa32c7d_0
pycocotools               2.0.2            py36h8c4c3a4_1    conda-forge
pytorch                   1.0.0           py3.6_cuda9.0.176_cudnn7.4.1_1    pytorch
scipy                     1.4.1            py36h2d22cac_3    conda-forge
torchvision               0.2.1                      py_2    pytorch
```

[image]

Comment: "I know about the error "truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous", but I don't know when you can have syntax like that without throwing the error. Is a solution downgrading my version of Numpy?" I posit that you _don't_ know what that error means

Comment: It's not a case of the library version you're using. You can't downgrade to another numpy version to reverse this logic because it's precisely the logic the library was built on. You will need to get familiar with "array programming", "broadcasting" and the like

Comment: I'm familiar with the logic, but I'm not trying to change any code. Other people have implemented it, presumably without changing the code. I'm trying to figure out why it's not working when I thought I followed the installation instructions correctly

Comment: You probably need either an older numpy or a newer h5py (3.x). See https://github.com/h5py/h5py/pull/1394